# Customize action taken when not authenticated

Tags: security, symfony

I have a Symfony 2.1 application where, depending on the url requested, I want to take a different action when the user's credentials have expired. I'm using the fos_userbundle which, by default, redirects to the login url. In my case, instead of redirecting, I want to return special response that the client will handle.

**Idea #1:**
I'm not sure exactly what I need to do to accomplish this. I've stepped through the code and found where the `Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall\ExceptionListener` is catching the exception that was thrown and eventually a `RedirectResponse` is set. I think I need to hook into here somewhere and set a different response but I haven't found it yet.

**Idea #2:**
I think I maybe need to setup another firewall that will handle the missing credentials differently. This seems like it would be a lot more work and doesn't quite *feel* right.

Both of my ideas may be way off base. It seems like it shouldn't be that difficult of a think to figure out, but I've searched high and low and can't find an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if they've changed the format for kernel listeners in 2.1 vs 2.0, but perhaps you could create a listener that handles the onKernelRequest method and checks to see if they are authenticated.

```
kernel.listener.pageloadlistener:
    class: Acme\DemoBundle\EventListener\PageLoadListener
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.request, method: onKernelRequest  }

class PageLoadListener
{
    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
       //Do whatever here, you could pass in the security context in the construct of this class to get the user
    }
}
```